# append string to window.location url in xsl

Tags: html, xslt

I am trying to construct a url (i.e link to the url) which is the current url of page and append it to some string value.
lets say the current url is https://localhost.com/xyz?abc=1&view=list
and string is dynamic which is time value in milliseconds.
I tried below code in xsl, but its not working, Can someone please suggest on solution.

```
<a class="time">
                        <xsl:variable
                                name="newUrl"
                                select="concat('{$window.location.href}=&quot;', ./time, '&quot;')">
                        </xsl:variable>

                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$newUrl'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </a>
```

Comment: Where is the variable `$window.location.href` defined? You cannot expect it to magically contain the value of the Javascript property `window.location.href`.

Comment: Its not defined, i want similar behavior in xsl. I just mentioned about window.location.href for the information on having this in xsl. Can you please suggest a way on getting the url in xsl.

Answer (score 0):

<xsl:value-of select="@url"/> to be used to get url. I can use concat to append url to some other string. Thanks for everyone's time in checking this query.